# The post method not displaying any message in python 3

Tags: python, webserver

I am using `python3` and I am creating simple web server that contains two get methods and one post method.

The get method is working fine but the `post` method is not displaying any message.

Here is the code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
```

import cgi
class webServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

```
def do_GET(self):
    try:
        if self.path.endswith("/hello"):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            output = ""
            output += "<html><body>"
            output += "<h1>Hello!</h1>"
            output += '''<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'><h2>What would you like me to say?</h2><input name="message" type="text" ><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>'''
            output += "</body></html>"
            self.wfile.write(bytes(output,'UTF-8'))
            print (output)
            return

        if self.path.endswith("/hola"):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            output = ""
            output += "<html><body>"
            output += "<h1>&#161 Hola !</h1>"
            output += '''<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'><h2>What would you like me to say?</h2><input name="message" type="text" ><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>'''
            output += "</body></html>"
            self.wfile.write(bytes(output,'UTF-8'))
            print (output)
            return

    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

def do_POST(self):
    try:
        self.send_response(301)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(
            self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
        if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
            fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
            messagecontent = fields.get('message')
        output = ""
        output += "<html><body>"
        output += " <h2> Okay, how about this: </h2>"
        output += "<h1> %s </h1>" % messagecontent[0]
        output += '''<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'><h2>What would you like me to say?</h2><input name="message" type="text" ><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>'''
        output += "</body></html>"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(output,'UTF-8'))
        print (output)
    except:
        pass

def main():
    try:
        port = 8080
        server = HTTPServer(('', port), webServerHandler)
        print ("Web Server running on port %s" % port)
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print (" ^C entered, stopping web server....")
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Weird question but what does do_POST apply to? I see that you have `if self.path.endswith("/hello")` in your get section but nothing in the POST? I am a python noob but it looks odd, could you explain why?

Comment: Using a bare `except` and silently ignoring the exception with a `pass` is a bit risky. Worth double checking that an exception isn't getting thrown and swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple exemple of how to specify and catch your request types.

You can choose the access route for your function, as well as the methods usable with the route. Once inside your function, you can catch the `request.method` type, and handle your case from there.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        do_the_login()
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        get_user_info()
    else:
        print("Unsupported request")
```